# drop record based on multile columns value using pyspark

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe like below :

[image: Acutal Dataframe]

I wanted to keep only one record if two column `uniq_id` and `date_time` have same value.

Expected Output :

[image]

I wanted to achieve this using pyspark.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `uniq_id` and `date_time` and use `first()`

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.groupBy("uniq_id", "date_time").agg(F.first("col_1"), F.first("col_2"), F.first("col_3")).show()
```

Comment: :How we can keep the predefine value's record only in this case  instead of selecting first?

Answer (score 0):

I can't get how you compare int column and timestamp one(though it can be done with casting timestamp to int) but such a filtering can be made via

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# assume you already have your DataFrame
df = df.filter(F.col('first_column_name') == F.col('second_column_name'))
```

or just

```
df = df.filter('first_column_name = second_column_name')
```